# Cumulative column values from dates current and previous

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table of registrations, around 300K records. I need a SQL statement that will show the total number of registrations for that particular day?

```
select
count('x'),CONVERT(varchar(12),date_created,111)
from reg group by
cONVERT(varchar(12),date_created,111)
order by
CONVERT(varchar(12),date_created,111)
```

Result of this query:

```
169      2011/03/24
3016     2011/03/25
2999     2011/03/26
```

Desired outcome:

```
 2011/03/25  3016+169
 2011/03/26  2999+3016+169
```

How can this be done?

Comment: Oh, I see [sql-server] is reserved for MS :o Very misleading.

Comment: @vbence: Sounds like you haven't heard of SQL Server.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SQL_Server

Comment: @p.campbell Wow.. so much hostility in such a short comment.

Comment: More humor needed all around.   C'mon guys, put it together!

Comment: +1 for good question.  I edited (needs approval) to remove unnecessary intro "fluff".

Comment: @vbence: no hostility. Just noted that you asked whether this was MySQL when it was clearly marked twice (title and tags) as SQL Server. StackOverflow's tag is not misleading, it's explicit.

Comment: It was misleading to me, and believe it or not, I have heared of MS-SQL. But seeng a tag like this just does not communicate it. Now I know that thag is used for MS-SQL, but a [foo-bar] tag would communicate the same meaning with the same accuracy. - But this is a discussion about the tag itself and quite offtopic here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is two versions to do this. I have tested with 100000 rows spread over 6000 days on a really slow computer with not enough memory, and that shows that the cte version is faster than the loop version. The other versions suggested here (so far) is a lot slower, provided that I have understood the problem correctly.

**Recursive CTE** (10 seconds)

```
-- Table variable to hold count for each day
declare @DateCount table(d int, c int, rn int)
insert into @DateCount
  select 
    datediff(d, 0, date_created) as d,
    count(*) as c,
    row_number() over(order by datediff(d, 0, date_created)) as rn
  from reg
  group by datediff(d, 0, date_created)

-- Recursive cte using @DateCount to calculate the running sum
;with DateSum as
(
  select 
    d, c, rn
  from @DateCount
  where rn = 1
  union all
  select 
    dc.d, ds.c+dc.c as c, dc.rn
  from DateSum as ds
    inner join @DateCount as dc
      on ds.rn+1 = dc.rn  
)
select
  dateadd(d, d, 0) as date_created,
  c as total_num
from DateSum
option (maxrecursion 0)
```

**Loop** (14 seconds)

```
-- Table variable to hold count for each day
declare @DateCount table(d int, c int, rn int, cr int)
insert into @DateCount
  select 
    datediff(d, 0, date_created) as d,
    count(*) as c,
    row_number() over(order by datediff(d, 0, date_created)) as rn,
    0
  from reg
  group by datediff(d, 0, date_created)

declare @rn int = 1

-- Update cr with running sum
update dc set
  cr = dc.c  
from @DateCount as dc
where rn = @rn

while @@rowcount = 1
begin
  set @rn = @rn + 1

  update dc set
    cr = dc.c + (select cr from @DateCount where rn = @rn - 1)  
  from @DateCount as dc
  where rn = @rn
end

-- Get the result
select
  dateadd(d, d, 0) as date_created,
  cr as total_num
from @DateCount
```

**Edit 1 The really fast version**

[The quirky update](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/68467/)

```
-- Table variable to hold count for each day
declare @DateCount table(d int primary key, c int, cr int)
insert into @DateCount
  select 
    datediff(d, 0, date_created) as d,
    count(*) as c,
    0
  from reg
  group by datediff(d, 0, date_created)

declare @rt int = 0
declare @anchor int

update @DateCount set
  @rt = cr = @rt + c,
  @anchor = d
option (maxdop 1)

-- Get the result
select
  dateadd(d, d, 0) as date_created,
  cr as total_num
from @DateCount                
order by d
```

Comment: +1 The quirky update technique is the fastest - Just not at all documented or guaranteed! You should really at the very least have a clustered index and `MAXDOP 1` set though (as discussed here http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/68467/)

Comment: @Martin - "Not documented or guaranteed" could be a valid reason to choose the slower recursive cte version instead if performance is reasonable. Perhaps the update can fail because the order of the update is not guaranteed. It would be bad if it started to do updates from the bottom or if SQL Server makes a choice to run the update in parallel. I have no idea if that is likely to happen. I will test this at work tomorrow where I have a computer with more than one processor :).

Comment: @Martin - Did not read your edited comment before I posted mine. Clustered index and `maxdop 1` sounds like the solution to the stuff I worried about.

Comment: this is brilliant.. All of them run super fast as well.. 0-2ms.. i will dissect the code to make sense of it.. should i use the cte method though? is it more reliable?

Comment: @Martin - I updated the "quirky update". Without the primary key on `d` in `@DateCount` it fails with large resultsets (50000 different days). I have not been able to make it fail without `maxdop 1` but the option should be there, just in case.

Comment: @Alessandro - I have modified the "quirky update" version. The previous version might fail so please use the new one.

Answer (score 2):

Simply use a `SUM` to get a cumulative count:

```
SELECT reg1.date_created,       
       SUM(reg2.val) AS CumulativeValue
FROM (
       select count(*) as RegCountForDay,
              date_created
       from  reg 
       group by  date_created
     )  AS reg1
LEFT JOIN reg AS reg2 ON (reg2.date_created <= reg1.date_created)
GROUP BY reg1.date_created
```

Comment: I think this would give exactly the same result as the two prevoious answers.

Comment: @vbence: fire up SQL Management Studio, paste in this answer, and execute it. It's SUM'ing on `r2`, not `r1`.

Comment: At that time I assumed that mine also gave the correct results. :)

Answer (score 2):

Currently you have 2 options: first is using join as proposed by vbence, second is subquery :

```
SELECT r1.date_created, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM reg r2 
WHERE r2.date_created<=r1.date_created) AS total_num
FROM reg r1;
```

These 2 approaches generate similar execution plans.

In the future, when SQLServer implements `ORDER BY` for `OVER` with aggregate functions, you will be able to write

```
SELECT date_created, 
COUNT(*) OVER(ORDER BY date_created) as total_num
FROM reg;
```

Comment: 3 options - The third is using a cursor, or [the CLR to act as a faster cursor](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/adam_machanic/archive/2006/07/12/running-sums-yet-again-sqlclr-saves-the-day.aspx)

Comment: @Martin: Sure, you can get the same results with cursors, but cursors have performance overheads, so I would not use them in such cases...

Comment: Depends how many rows need to be processed. The triangular join workload grows proportional to the square of the number of rows. The cursor worload linearly.

Comment: @Martin: I agree, it can make sense. Maybe with a huge number of rows cursor solution will behave better. However, SQL Server is optimized for set-based operations, and I believe that for the most part set-based solution will outperform cursor-based one.

Comment: Yep. I agree on that. Running Totals is the classic example where this isn't true however and the OP mentions they have 300K records. The cursor will comfortably win here. However it also seems like they are only interested in partitioning by day which could be leveraged to bring the workload down.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one.

```
SELECT r1.date_created,
    COUNT(*) AS number
FROM (SELECT distinct(date_created) FROM reg) AS r1
    LEFT JOIN reg AS r2 ON (r2.date_created <= r1.date_created)
GROUP BY r1.date_created
```

Of course you have to index your table with something like:

```
CREATE INDEX datefilter ON reg (date_created);
```

Comment: It would give you the number of registrations for a certain day and for all the previous days combined. This is as cumulative as it gets.

Comment: @p.campbell I stand corrected. Somehow I assumed that `r1` had distinct values. Thank you for taking time for your demonstration.

Answer (score 1):

you can solve this problem through below sql query..You have given two columns `col1=Number` and `col2=Date`

```
Select DATE,OUTPUT=SUM(InnerValue) from
(
  Select T1.Date, T1.Number, InnerValue=ISNULL(T2.Number,0)  from
  (
   Select ID=DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY DATE),Date,Number from YourTable
  ) As T1
  LEFT JOIN
  (
   Select ID=DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY DATE),Date,Number from YourTable
  ) AS T2
  ON T1.ID >= T2.ID
) As MainTable GROUP BY DATE
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use CLR to define your own Running Sum Function as described in the followig link:

http://pavelpawlowski.wordpress.com/2010/09/30/sql-server-and-fastest-running-totals-using-clr/